# how to limit writing a file using filehelpers C#

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I need to manage a text file upto 3gb size. I'd like to keep the file under 3gb with new text being added to the end of the file and text at the beginning of the file being removed. I am experimenting doing this thing with using filehelpers library.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Message>();
            string filepath = @"C:\Users\ConsoleApp1\testfile.txt");
            long length = new System.IO.FileInfo(filepath).Length;
            var records = engine.ReadFile(filepath);
            if (ConvertBytesToMegabytes(length) > 3000) {
                engine.BeforeWriteRecord += BeforeWriteEvent;
            }
            engine.WriteFile("source2.txt", records);

        }

        private static void BeforeWriteEvent(EngineBase engine, BeforeWriteEventArgs<Message> e)
        {
        }

        private static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
        {
            return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
        }
```

i am not sure how to achieve this functionality using filehelpers.Can someone help me out in this.

Comment: What problem you are facing here?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i am not sure how to remove records from top while file size is going bigger and writing will continue

Comment: This will probably never work as you expect. If you want to remove text from the beginning you have to rewrite the whole file. This will at least not be possible with high performance. A solution for you might be to always append to a file and once it has reached the maximum size you rename it to .bak and create a new file.